# Re-assigning a selected value from a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to re-assign a selected value from a dropdown list, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried a couple of things, but no luck yet...

1) that.value = "Aqua";

2) $(that).val("Aqua");

3) $(that).attr("value", "Aqua");

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" name="name" id="selectedColor" required >
  <option value="" selected>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="Blue">Option 1</option> 
  <option value="Orange">Option 2</option> 
  <option value="Red">Option 3</option>       
</select>

<script>
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "Blue" ) {

           that.value = "Aqua";  /* <----- re-assign the value */

          /*  commented out */
          /* $(that).val("Aqua");
           $(that).attr("value", "Aqua"); */ 

    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does *"reassign the value"* even mean? A proper explanation of expected behavior will help

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to make (that.value = "Aqua") when it was initially set to blue upon selection from the dropdown. So, I'm checking for it (that.value == "Blue"), then trying to change the value. Does that help?

Comment: So if I select "blue" then it should change to "aqua" and blue is no longer a choice? Sounds very strange

Comment: Blue's still a valid choice. I'm just wanna create some filtering logic from that color spectrum choice. At any rate, I just don't know how to modify the value, so it's Aqua instead of Blue. :-/

Comment: Then this really is confusing and you should write a properly detailed explnation of exactly what you want to accomplish .. in the question and in a way there is no ambiguity

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helpful below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing

Do you mean that change the text after you select? You can do the code below

```
</script>
<select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" name="name" id="selectedColor" required >
  <option value="" selected>Select an Option</option>
  <option id="change" value="Blue">Option 1</option> 
  <option value="Orange">Option 2</option> 
  <option value="Red">Option 3</option>       
</select>

<script>
function yesnoCheck(e) {
    if (e.value == "Blue" ) {

           $("#change").text("Aqua"); 
    }    
}
</script>
```

Or, you want to change the option value from "Blue" to "Aqua", then

```
$("#change").val("Aqua");
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Salomon! Change the "text." I see now that had I used that word, it would have helped you guys! Thanks again!